# cannot search a text file in php

Tags: php, file

I coded an html script which has a text field and I recieve a piece of php source code from user with post method and save it to a text file , after that I want to search that text to find these keywords :

> "GET" "include" "include_once" "require" "require_once" (without "")

I want to write a simple scanner for Local File Inclusion Vulnerability(LFI) , that you can give the code and this program test it .

here is my html script :

Comment: It cannot search correct ! But it does not give any errors it just gives some warnings like : // <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: data in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\rfi-z.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
It might not to be vulnerable !
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\rfi-z.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />

Comment: Please define `cannot search correct`. Simply stating that it doesn't work isn't sufficient!

Comment: OK , as an example I give these to my program : GETasdadadrequire as far as I said I want to find keywords like GET or require,but my program cannot search correct and the result is : It might not to be vulnerable !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your regex is wrong (you're escaping the $ and you could just have easily used `/GET/` as `/^.*GET.*$/m` from what I can understand of your intentions) and you close the file and then continue to use it after doing god knows what to it at the beginning, your code seems to work ok. I cleaned some of the crap out of it and ran it and it worked fine.

```
<?php
$contents = "GETincludeinclude_oncerequirerequire_once";

$pattern = "/^.*GET.*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "You used GET method !\n";
}
else{
   echo "It might not to be vulnerable !\n";
}

$pattern = "/^.*include.*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "You used include function !\n";
}
else{
   echo "It might not to be vulnerable !\n";
}

$pattern = "/^.*include_once.*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "You used include_once function !\n";
}
else{
   echo "It might not to be vulnerable !\n";
}

$pattern = "/^.*require.*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "You used require function !\n";
}
else{
   echo "It might not to be vulnerable !\n";
}

$pattern = "/^.*require_once.*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "You used require_once function !\n";
}
else{
   echo "It might not to be vulnerable !\n";
}
?>
```

Above code outputs:

```
You used GET method !
You used include function !
You used include_once function !
You used require function !
You used require_once function !
```

Comment: thanks for your attention , but it still does not work. for example : give this to the program : hellowhatsupman! and the result is : "You used GET method ! You used include function ! You used include_once function ! You used require function ! You used require_once function !"

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done to get that result, but with the input `hellowhatsupman!` I get `It might not to be vulnerable !` for all the tests.

Comment: here is my code: http://s1.picofile.com/file/7482063545/Untitled.png (because first of all I want to receive data from a form !)

Comment: Do you **need** to save the input to a file? Change line 13 to `$contents = $_POST['data'];` and get rid of the stuff above it.